# Problema ao adicionar uma FOREIGN KEY

Tags: laravel

Pessoal estou com problema ao adicionar uma `foreign key` no laravel 5.4. Segue os códigos das `migrations` abaixo:

```
Schema::create('anexos_posts', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->string('anexo');
        $table->integer('post_id')->unsigned();
        $table->timestamps();
    });
```

Logo em seguida é executada outra `migration` adicionando a `foreign`:

```
Schema::table('anexos_posts', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->foreign('post_id')->references('id')->on('postagens');
    });
```

Erro:

> Schema::table('anexos_posts', function (Blueprint $table) {
>               $table->foreign('post_id')->references('id')->on('postagens');
>           });
>                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                               In Connection.php line 647:
>                                                                                                                                                                             SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1215 Cannot add `foreign key`
>   constraint (SQL: alter table `anexos_posts` add constraint
>   `anexos_posts_post_id_foreign` foreign key (     `post_id`) references
>   `postagens` (`id`))
>
> In Connection.php line 449:
>                                                                                SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1215 Cannot add foreign key constraint

Comment: Creio que isso irá te ajudar. https://stackoverflow.com/a/23587127/4312593

Comment: Já tentei o mesmo e o erro persiste.

Comment: Para estabelecer uma constraint, os campos devem ter o mesmo tipo e tamanho, confira como está sem criado a `id` da sua tabela `postagens`, pois rodei as migrações sem erros.

Answer (score 0):

Você pode fazer tudo de uma vez só.
Segue um exemplo de um financeiro que eu fiz.

```
Schema::create('financeiro', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->date('data');
        $table->date('vencimento');
        $table->date('data_pagamento');
        $table->enum('status', array('PROVISIONADO','EFETIVADO'));
        $table->enum('tipo_lancamento', array('CRÉDITO','DÉBITO'));
        $table->integer('pessoa_id')->unsigned();
        $table->integer('user_id')->unsigned()->nullable();
        $table->integer('filial_id')->unsigned()->nullable();
        $table->integer('modalidade_pagamento_id')->unsigned()->nullable();
        $table->integer('bancos_id')->unsigned()->nullable();
        $table->float('valor')->nullable();
        $table->float('descontos')->nullable();
        $table->float('juros')->nullable();
        $table->float('valor_cobrado')->nullable();
        $table->text('historico')->nullable();
        $table->text('observacoes')->nullable();
        $table->foreign('pessoa_id')->references('id')->on('pessoas');
        $table->foreign('user_id')->references('id')->on('users');
        $table->foreign('filial_id')->references('id')->on('equipe');
        $table->foreign('modalidade_pagamento_id')->references('id')->on('modalidade_pagamento');
        $table->foreign('bancos_id')->references('id')->on('bancos');
        $table->timestamps();
    });
```